# How to set axios base url in nuxt config using gitlab variables?

Tags: gitlab, nuxt.js, gitlab-ci

I have a nuxt application which uses following configuration (nuxt.config.js)

```
 axios: {
    /* set API_URL environment variable to configure access to the API
     */
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL || 'http://localhost:5000',
    redirectError: {
      401: '/Identity/Account/Login',
      404: '/notfound'
    }
  },
```

I want to set the API_URL using gitlab variables(settings => CI/CD => Variables) but it doesn't seem to pick it

[image]

Comment: where do you try yo execture `nuxt.config.js` ? In your container ? in your `gitlab-ci.yml` ?

Comment: @ Nicolas Pepinster Gitlab shell runner installed in the linux environment

Comment: could you copy the part of your `gitlab-ci.yml` where you use `nuxt.config.js` in your question ?

Comment: I am setting the variable using the gitlab ui settings => CI/CD => Variables as shown in the image